# How to generate distinct permutations of a vector in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, permutation

Suppose that there is a vector with only binary elements like this:

```
X = [0, 0, 1, 1]
```

The only distinct permutations are:

```
X = [0, 0, 1, 1]
X = [0, 1, 0, 1]
X = [0, 1, 1, 0]
X = [1, 0, 0, 1]
X = [1, 0, 1, 0]
X = [1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Is there an efficient way to do this in C++?

Comment: [`std::next_permutation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that returns a boolean value to check if a permutation is lexicographically greater than the previous one. I want to generate distinct permutations.

Comment: @Nishchay: That's just what the return value is. The function also transforms the range *into* that next permutation. It's the first sentence in the link you were given.

Comment: You can call it in a loop to get all possible permutations. See the example in the linked reference.

Comment: Try to see this link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/distinct-permutations-string-set-2/ , and change the ```string``` with a ```vector```

Comment: @NicolBolas Understood. I need to run it in a loop right? How many times should I do it?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude how many times should I loop it?

Comment: It returns "`false` if the last permutation was reached and the range was reset to the first permutation" (from the linked reference). So just keep looping until it returns `false`. Again, please see the example in the linked reference. You could easily switch out the string for your vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `std::next_permutation`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cstdio>

int
main()
{
  std::array<int, 4> arr{ 0, 0, 1, 1 };

  /* Sort the array if necessary */
  std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());

  do {
    for (auto const e : arr)
      std::printf("%d ", e);
    std::putchar('\n');
  } while (std::next_permutation(arr.begin(), arr.end()));
}
```

Output:

```
0 0 1 1 
0 1 0 1 
0 1 1 0 
1 0 0 1 
1 0 1 0 
1 1 0 0
```

[Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7pqMGL)

Comment: Why the `std::printf` and `std::putchar` in C++?

Comment: @BessieTheCow why not?